# /bin/bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory - error during CocoaPods installation

Tags: cocoapods, react-native-ios, macos-catalina

I am trying to initialize a React-Native project, and following the docs, I did:

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Also uninstalling react-native-cli, as suggested in the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/getting-started).
Nothing wrong with those steps, until:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Then I got a error message:

```
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               


                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
⠏ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.61.5)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.61.5)
Installing React (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core (0.61.5)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTText (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.61.5)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsi (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.61.5)
Installing ReactCommon (0.61.5)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

/bin/bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

I tried to follow the recommendation and run

```
cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install
```

But got another error here:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.61.5)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.61.5)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing RCTRequired (0.61.5)
Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.61.5)
Installing React (0.61.5)
Installing React-Core (0.61.5)
Installing React-CoreModules (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTBlob (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTImage (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTLinking (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTSettings (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTText (0.61.5)
Installing React-RCTVibration (0.61.5)
Installing React-cxxreact (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsi (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.61.5)
Installing React-jsinspector (0.61.5)
Installing ReactCommon (0.61.5)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
#
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

set -e

PLATFORM_NAME="${PLATFORM_NAME:-iphoneos}"
CURRENT_ARCH="${CURRENT_ARCH}"

if [ -z "$CURRENT_ARCH" ] || [ "$CURRENT_ARCH" == "undefined_arch" ]; then
    # Xcode 10 beta sets CURRENT_ARCH to "undefined_arch", this leads to incorrect linker arg.
    # it's better to rely on platform name as fallback because architecture differs between simulator and device

    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" == *"simulator"* ]]; then
        CURRENT_ARCH="x86_64"
    else
        CURRENT_ARCH="armv7"
    fi
fi

export CC="$(xcrun -find -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME cc) -arch $CURRENT_ARCH -isysroot $(xcrun -sdk $PLATFORM_NAME --show-sdk-path)"
export CXX="$CC"

# Remove automake symlink if it exists
if [ -h "test-driver" ]; then
    rm test-driver
fi

./configure --host arm-apple-darwin

# Fix build for tvOS
cat << EOF >> src/config.h

/* Add in so we have Apple Target Conditionals */
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#include <Availability.h>
#endif

/* Special configuration for AppleTVOS */
#if TARGET_OS_TV
#undef HAVE_SYSCALL_H
#undef HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H
#undef OS_MACOSX
#endif

/* Special configuration for ucontext */
#undef HAVE_UCONTEXT_H
#undef PC_FROM_UCONTEXT
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__rip
#elif defined(__i386__)
#define PC_FROM_UCONTEXT uc_mcontext->__ss.__eip
#endif
EOF

# Prepare exported header include
EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR="exported/glog"
mkdir -p exported/glog
cp -f src/glog/log_severity.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/raw_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/stl_logging.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"
cp -f src/glog/vlog_is_on.h "$EXPORTED_INCLUDE_DIR/"

/bin/bash: ./configure: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to do it the old way too, by re-installing react-native-cli, but get the same error.

Can someone please help explain what's the problem (bash / glog / some configuration file?
And how should I fix this?

My environment is currently:

MacOS Catalina 10.15.3

XCode cersion 11.3.1 (11C504)

Node version 13.8.0

npm version 6.13.6

Homebrew version 2.2.7

Gem version 3.1.2

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

Your help is greatly appreciated ! :) thank you

Comment: The `/bin/sh^M` suggests that your file is formatted with DOS line endings (CRLF) instead of Unix (LF).

Comment: What file should i format to Unix then? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally someone solved it with Sublime Text editor, since converting the file with dos2unix and vim didn't work somehow. Please follow the [link here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28217#issuecomment-593804788).